# Checkered Texture from Nodes

Tags: texturing, node-editor, groups

Greetings dear 3D artists!

I am trying to create a checkered material from groups of nodes. I am using the following groups of nodes:

['Checkers V2.0'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rX-C5C4xlI) - Generates checkered material.

['Grid'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsZoJBeAWGc) - Generates crosses.

By combining the nodes as shown in the figure, I discovered the problem of precise positioning of the crosses.

What can I do to place crosses at the nodes of the yellow grid?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how those 2 node groups work but I could place mapping node as input into Vector position of those nodes and try to match their position or give it one same node (may not work, it depends on those node groups)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this nodes setup here:

[image]

and if you change now the x/y/z location of the mapping nodes you can move them as you want.

[image]

Comment: OK. Thanks! It has already begun to work out.

Comment: you are welcome